# php wikipedia (change information in div)

Tags: php, database, wikipedia

Does someone know how I can make a Wikipedia for my website

-change the information and send it to my mail

-can only changed if logged

I think I can make the script for "only changing when logged" by my self, but I need someone for the begin. I really dont know how i can make this script

Web-stars

```
<div>this is my information, if you are logged, than you can change me and send your change to my emailadress</div>

<input type="button" name="changediv" valuee="change" />
```

Comment: This question is incredibly vague. Do you have any existing code, or even structure? You say a "sort of Wikipedia" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: sorry I changed my question! and no i don't have a code or structure. If someone can help me with a code or structure it would be nice!

Comment: Do you mean "a wiki", rather than "a Wikipedia"?

Comment: yeah sorry but indeed, thats what i mean
is there a handmake script for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You need only to install this script http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki on your host. It's a PHP script wich is a copy of Wikipedia template.

Comment: it doesnt work, there are a few errors and its sooo big, I think if there is a handmake php script for, that I only need a few pages. (index, preperation, and the page if preperation succeed)

Comment: if you don't want to lose time writting your own script, just look throw these [link](http://www.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=8)